# How to add scroll effect HTML

Tags: jquery, scroll, parallax

I have came across the following website:

http://lookbook.slam.com/en/

I wonder that how they implement the scroll and parallax effect to each elements,

if anybody can help that would be great.

thanks.

Comment: Use search engine for that. There's a lot of tuts out there.

Comment: could you please name any tutorial ..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you should be looking for something called: one-page website using javascript. see this simple example: 
https://codeplanet.io/how-to-make-a-single-page-website/

and you can find a nice empty simple template here, so you can read it and do some editing on it: 
http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Comment: The main ideas is to animate every single element on the page but in different speed to each other. simple smooth page scrolling is not an issue.

Comment: as I guess, you can use Canvas. see this article: https://www.kirupa.com/html5/animating_many_things_on_a_canvas.htm